# habilitar modulo de PDO mysql y php en godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, pdo

Tengo un hosting windows classic con iis y php 5.3 en godaddy 
ahi mi pagina web se conecta a una base de datos mysql

esta es mi conexion

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=dbgts.db.2365702.3ed.hostedresource.net;dbname=dbase';
$username = 'user';
$password = '12345';


function conecta() {
    global $dsn, $username, $password;
  try {

      $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
      $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die( 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage() );
  }
}

function validaSesion(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

pero al hacer la conexion me sale este error Query failed: could not find driver

me comunique con soporte y em dicen que tengo que hacer un archivo php5.ini y ahi llamar 
las librerias de pdo y mysql ya lo cree pero sigue sin funcionarme

este es mi php5.ini

```
rAddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php4
register_globals = Off
session.save_path = "D:\Hosting\2365702\html\session"
display_errors = ON
log_errors = On
error_log="D:\Hosting\2365702\html"
memory_limit = 48M
max_execution_time = 240
max_input_time = 180
post_max_size = 8M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 256M
extension_dir = "D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext"
upload_tmp_dir = "D:\Hosting\2365702\html\temp"
[PHP_PDO]
extension=D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext\php_pdo.dll
[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]
extension=D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext\php_mysql.dll
extension=D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext\php_mysqli.dll
extension=D:\Hosting\2365702\html\ext\php_curl.dll

[Pdo]
pdo_mysql.default_socket="MySQL"
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size=2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
```

cree una carpeta en el root de mi hosting llamada ext donde puse todos los dlls 
pero en mi archivo info.php me sigue saliendo  PDO drivers  no value
y en extension_dir  me sale     C:\php53\ext

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]!. Te recomiendo que hagas es [tour] y asi ganes tu primera medalla. Tambien es importante repasar [ask]

Comment: [Quiza esto es lo que buscas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256416/pdo-not-working-in-godaddy-server)

Comment: Una cosa es crear un nuevo fichero .ini para que el php lo cargue y otra que realmente lo esté llamando, ejecuta el phpinfo y mira si estás cargando el fichero. Si lo estás incluyendo bien, en el mismo phpinfo deberías ver las extensiones si están habilitadas. Si carga el fichero pero no las extensiones es porque no estás utilizando las dll para las versiones correctas revisa eso, puedes también habilitar los errores al inicio y reiniciar el servicio para ver alguna pista adicional.